# Replacing NULL values Impala query

Tags: sql, math, null, impala

I'm trying to create a SQL statement in Imapala that would replace NULL values with 1.  The fields generated out of this output will then be multiplied by each other.

I thought `coalesce` would work but I'm still NULLS in the output.  Below is my syntax, do I have the 1 in the wrong place.  How would I write this?  Please help.

```
SUM(
    COALSECE(
        CASE WHEN a.level = '8' AND a.assembly_flag = 'X' THEN
            COALSECE( a.inclusion_kg, 1 )
        END
    )
) level_8_inclusion
```

Tried to use coalesce in different places in the syntax.

Comment: `COALSECE` requires 2 arguments - but your first (outer) call-site only specifies 1 argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in comments by @Dai, `COALESCE` requires 2 arguments :

This will return 1 when if the sum is NULL

```
COALESCE(
    SUM(
        CASE WHEN a.level = '8' AND a.assembly_flag = 'X' THEN
            a.inclusion_kg
        END
    ), 1 -- second argument
) level_8_inclusion
```

Comment: I tried this with a 1 in the second argument but because of the SUM it returns a SUM of the aggregation.  I have 10 other statements just like this which will then be multiplied by one another so I would need the value to return a 1 when there is NULL.  This is what I tried - SUM(
    COALESCE(
        CASE WHEN a.level = '8' AND a.assembly_flag = 'X' THEN
            COALESCE( a.inclusion_kg, 1 )
        END, 1

Comment: Not clear what you are asking, can you edit your question and share some simple data and the expected output ?

Comment: Perhaps you need something like : COALESCE(
       SUM(
         CASE WHEN a.level = '8' AND a.assembly_flag = 'X' THEN
            a.inclusion_kg
         END
        ), 1 ) level_8_inclusion

Comment: COALESCE( SUM( CASE WHEN a.level = '8' AND a.assembly_flag = 'X' THEN a.inclusion_kg END ), 1 ) level_8_inclusion  --- this worked perfectly.  I tried this earlier but my syntax was out of place.  Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

I think you want some kind of conditional aggregation here, perhaps:

```sql
SUM(CASE WHEN a.level = '8' AND a.assembly_flag = 'X'
         THEN COALESCE(a.inclusion_kg, 1)
         ELSE 0 END) AS level_8_inclusion
```

Comment: I need the NULL to be a 1 so when I multiply level 8 * level 9 it should return a 1 if one or both values are 0